# How do I install git issues?

Tags: git, issue-tracking

I feel like I must be missing something, but the [git issues](https://github.com/jwiegley/git-issues) README doesn't say how to install itself. How do I install git issues?

I just cloned git-issues, so I'm using the latest copy.

EDIT:

so I "installed" git according to the answer below, but here's what happens:

```
sudo cp git-issues gitshelve.py t_gitshelve.py /usr/local/bin
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
$ cd /dir/to/git/project
$ git issues init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/git-issues", line 1035, in <module>
    copy(join(dirname(__file__), "README"), issuesdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 88, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/README'
```

So I had to rename README.textile to README and then place that in `/usr/local/bin`

I'm sorry, but that feels like something wrong is happening. Having a README file in `/usr/local/bin` shouldn't have to happen. Am I missing something here?

EDIT 2:

even after moving README file, `git help issues` returns `No manual entry for git-issues`. How can I get that to work as well? (now I'm beginning to feel like a big complainer :) )

EDIT 3:

```
$ git issues push
Unknown command push
```

Why won't the 'push' functionality work either? All I've done is cp the files to /usr/local/bin , and then I also cp'ed the same files to /usr/lib/git-core to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it (the `git-issues` script) anywhere in your `PATH` and `chmod +x` it. (The `.py` file also needs to be in the same directory.)

Comment: It does not appear to have a manpage that comes with it, so you can't "get 'git help issues' to work", since it has nothing to work *with*. Overall, it seems like a poorly packaged tool.

Comment: I agree, it's poorly packaged; so I'm just abandoning it. Thanks for the help.